# Expression to Highlight certain Cells depending on the Date

Tags: devexpress, expression

I need to highlight a cell in the Customer Rate column based on that it is 1 week past a delivery date. I have already created a variable for the style - xrControlStyle2 with the color it needs to be.

```
Iif(AddDays([delivereddt], 7),[xrControlStyle2],[thirdparty_cost])
```

The result I get is that the Customer Rate column which is thirdParty_cost is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the textbox **Text Box Properties > Fill > Fill Color** and write the following expression:

```
=IIF(Today() > DateAdd("ww", 1, CDate(Fields!DeliveryDate)), "Red", "Green")
```

Comment: Thanks that works if I was using SSRS but I am working with DevExpress and the syntax is different.

Comment: Hmm a few days ago I am sure your post was tagged with SSRS. But I cant help you here with DevExpress...

Answer (score 0):

In DevExpress the expression is

```
Iif(Now() > AddDays(DeliveryDate,7), 'red', 'green')
```